# Proving differentiable function is continuous.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

To prove that if function has a derivative at a then it is continuous at $a$, my teacher did:

\begin{align}
& \|f(a+h)-f(a)\|=\|f(a+h)-f(a)+f'(a)~h-f'(a)~h\| \\[8pt]
\leq {} & \|f(a+h)-f(a)-f'(a)~h\|+\|f'(a)~h\| \\[8pt]
\leq {} & \|f(a+h)-f(a)-f'(a)~h\|+\|f'(a)\| \|h\| \\[8pt]
= {} & \underbrace{\left( \frac{\|f(a+h)-f(a)-f'(a)~h\|}{\|h\|}+\|f'(a)\| \right)}_{\text{finite no.}} \|h\|
\end{align}

> Hence, $\|f(a+h)-f(a)\|\rightarrow 0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$.

But my doubt is why can't we do it this way:

$$\|f(a+h)-f(a)\|=\left( \frac{\|f(a+h)-f(a)\|}{\|h\|}\|h\| \right)$$

> > now take limits as $h\rightarrow 0$.then  :
> >     \begin{align}\lim_{h\to 0} \|f(a+h)-f(a)\| & =\lim_{h\to 0} \left( \frac{\|f(a+h)-f(a)\|}{\|h\|}\right)\lim_{h\to 0}\|h\| \\[6pt]
> > &=f'(a)\cdot0 \\[6pt]
> > &=0\end{align}

Hence,lim$_{h \to 0}f(a+h)=f(a)$ so, function is continuous at $a$. Am I doing it correct this way?

Comment: Can you specify the domain and codomain of $f$ ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo $f$ is a function s.t.:$f$:$U\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I'm taking the course on Calculus of several variables,and I'm just referring teacher's notes.Here,$f:U\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$,where U is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$.f is said to be differentiable at $a\in U$ if lim$_{h\to 0}||f(a+h-f(a)-T(h)||/||h||$=0 for some $T\in L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$.

Comment: I removed my comment after seeing @Kim Jong Un's perfect answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your teacher's longer approach is that the total derivative $f'(a)$ is defined as the linear transformation satisfying
$$
\lim_{|h|\to 0}\frac{|f(a+h)-f(a)-f'(a)\cdot h|}{|h|}=0
$$
and **not**
$$
\lim_{|h|\to 0}\frac{|f(a+h)-f(a)|}{|h|}=f'(a).
$$
Notice that in the second case, the fraction is just scalar over scalar so the RHS cannot be a matrix.